# Message: Undefined variable: username Filename: views/receiver_view.php Line Number: 58

Tags: php

Brothers your help needed.

i am trying to develop a chat application in which i am displaying friends at the right top but         the following error occurs. i have tried again and again but cant solve the problem.
   my code is:

function is:

```
function get_sessionId() {

    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['usernames'] = $this->chat_model->show_user($session_id['id']);
    $this->load->view('chat_view',$data);

}
```

foreach loop is:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($users as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="set_user(<?php echo $row->id; ?>)">
           <?php echo $row->username;?>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

and the query that i have write in model is:

```
function show_user($sessionId) {

    $query = $this->db->query("select id, username from users where id <>'$sessionId'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Is `id` an int type in the database? if so, you need to remove `'$sessionId'` and replace it with `$sessionId` without the `''` encapsulation so it doesn't get treated as a string. Also, just so you know...the `<>` operator is `NOT EQUAL TO` essentially and therefore you're selecting all rows where the ID is not equivalent to the $sessionID, which surely can't be what you want.

Comment: offcourse the id in the database is of int type. i have done the same but the problem remains...any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you have assigned the users to:

```
$data['usernames'] = $this->chat_model->show_user($session_id['id']);
$this->load->view('chat_view', $data);
```

So in View Section it should be like this:

```
<?php foreach($usernames as $row): ?>
```

not

```
<?php foreach($users as $row): ?>
```